# Product of cotton-york tensor with ricci tensor

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, tensor, geometric-analysis

In the process of calculation of a problem in tensor analysis, I have encountered with an expression given by $$C^{ij}R_{ij}=0.$$

This is for a Riemannian manifold of dimension 3. Assuming the manifold is compact, what can be said about the manifold? Here $C^{ij}$ and $R_{ij}$ are Cotton-york tensor and Ricci tensor respectively.

Comment: Doesn't the Cotton tensor have three indices? In general, I get the impression that it's easier to produce and classify curvature scalars than it is to find any application or interpretation of a particular scalar.

Comment: This is a variant of cotton tensor called cotton-york tensor. It has two indices. You can also look at the paper titled " the cotton flow"

Comment: The manifold is Riemannian and dimension is three.

Comment: @BenCrowell: If the Cotton tensor is viewed as a one-form valued two-form, then on a $3$-manifold it can be identified with a tensor with two-indices via the metric duality of $1$ and $2$ forms, and this is often done.